# Microsoft account login server has detected too many repeated authentication attempts

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365

For 1 week, I have the following error when trying to open **Excel Online in Chrome**, whereas Excel Online in Safari works. Does anyone know how to fix it?

> Sign in
>
> Something went wrong and we can't sign you in right now. Please try again later.
>
> The Microsoft account login server has detected too many repeated authentication attempts. Please wait a moment and try again.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing everything (cache, cookies...)?

Comment: Sure, I have tried this...

Comment: Try to access in private mode. In chrome ctrl+shift+n

Comment: Are you able to sign in to [live.com](http://live.com/) from Chrome?

Comment: I did nothing special, but 2 weeks later the problem did not exist anymore. Thank you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to resolve the issue by **forcing sign-out** of your Microsoft account, **clearing Chrome cache, cookies, etc** (again), and then signing back in to Excel Online.

.

***Here are the steps:***

---

### Sign out of all Microsoft Accounts

1. Go to https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf and click `Sign Out` (if you weren't automatically signed out)
2. Go to https://login.live.com/logout.srf and click `Sign Out` (if you weren't automatically signed out)

---

### Clear cache and cookies in Google Chrome

1. Open Chrome.
2. On your browser toolbar, click `More`, `More` and then `More Tools` and then `Clear Browsing Data`.
3. In the `Clear browsing data` box, select the tickboxes for `Cookies and other site data` and `Cached images and files`.
4. Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. Choose `beginning of time` to delete everything.
5. Click `Clear browsing data`.

---

Finally, close Chrome, re-open, navigate to [Microsoft Excel Online](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx), and your issue should be resolved.

If all else fails, contact [Microsoft Excel Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/excel).

Comment: I have this problem again, and `Go to https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf` fixes it.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the update!  ...but I wonder why you keep having this problem.

Comment: @SoftTimur -  It's ironic...  Now I'm having the same problem you did, so I had to come back and find this post so I could fix it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open TOOLS in Internet Explorer
2. Click INTERNET OPTIONS
3. Go to PRIVACY
4. Click SITES
5. In MANAGE WEBSITES find and delete the ALWAYS BLOCK site which you cannot sign in. Restart IE.

Comment: Why would this be a solution? The question relates to Chrome browser, not Microsoft's Internet Explorer. Given that the user was able to login with Safari makes it also likely that this is MacOS.